# Protractor browser.executeScript throws 'SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list' Exception

Tags: javascript, dom, protractor, domdocument

**Background info**

I'm unable to click certain elements on the angular material 2 design website I am currently automating. As a result I'm having to implement a workaround of using the JavaScriptExecutor provided in the Protractor API. However I'm having issues when I want to query the dom and click the element using Javascript.

**What doesn't work**

```
  hardClickElement(by.css("input[placeholder='Search Accounts']"));

  function hardClickElement(by) {
    var locator = by.toString();
    if (locator.includes("css")) {
      console.log(`document.querySelector('${by.value}').click()`);
      browser.executeScript(`document.querySelector('${by.value}').click()`);
    }
  }
```

**What does work**

```
hardClickElement(by.css(".mat-menu-content button"));

  function hardClickElement(by) {
    var locator = by.toString();
    if (locator.includes("css")) {
      console.log(`document.querySelector('${by.value}').click()`);
      browser.executeScript(`document.querySelector('${by.value}').click()`);
    }
  }
```

**So...**

So my question is why am i getting the exception

> Failed: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

when executing the first block of code?

Answer (score 2):

You have this template string:

```
`document.querySelector('${by.value}').click()`
```

**Look at the result** with `console.log` before you pass it to `executeScript`.

You have `'` characters delimiting the string that is the attribute value.

The input value you are giving it:

```
input[placeholder='Search Accounts']
```

… also contains `'` characters. Inside a string delimited with `'` they will need escaping.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve the problem:

```
hardClickElement(by.css('input[placeholder="Search Accounts"]'));
```

*use double quotes inside single quotes*